# How can we send videos and GIFs with the preview in Bale messenger bot?

Tags: python, bale-messenger, balebot

I am creating a chatbot in Bale messenger using [this library](https://github.com/python-bale-bot/python-bale-bot).
Currently, the files and documents can be sent if the file_id is obtained before. The code below works perfectly fine.

```py
await callback.message.chat.send_document(document = "file_id", caption = "This is a video/GIF")
```

But when a GIF or a video is sent, it will be displayed in the chat as a document that you must download to watch. But the GIF should be played over and over again in the chat, so it should have a preview. Does anyone know how we can send the video with the preview?
I have also tried removing the caption. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The `sendVideo` method should be used for this. Also, go back to the [discussion](https://github.com/python-bale-bot/python-bale-bot/discussions/18) in the library for more information.